# [Jenkins]-How to use remote host repository(i.e., another computer files ) instead of using github repository?

Tags: android, git, jenkins

i created an Jenkins android application build using the git-hub repository .now i have to access the remote host that means another computer and fetch that remote host files then make a build in  my computer.

- can any one suggest me solution for this?
- Is this possible to build remote host file ?
- if it is possible means,suggest me procedure to build remote host
  files?

Answer (score 0):

already similar question asked here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576593/creating-a-jenkins-android-build-using-http-url/28577525?noredirect=1#comment45466802_28577525

and if you want to make HTTPS request to get your artifacts use below

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin

Its a very simple one which can be found using your search engine.